# How to add controls dynamically on button click in mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How to add controls dynamically on button click in mvc3

Comment: Could you add some detail to your question please? What, specifically, are you trying to achieve? What have you tried so far? Maybe post a code snippet of where you've got to with the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you meant controller actions, you could do it like:

```
@this.Html.Action("ActionName", "ControllerNAme")
```

But if you meant ASP.NET Webforms server controls, forget that. In MVC the alternative is to use [HTML helpers](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs).

Answer (score 0):

you can use ajax to call controller, pass parameters for control and it should return view(control). you should serialize view before returning.